# internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:190: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address

Tags: c++, gcc, sublimetext3, mingw, mingw32

> internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:190: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address.

I get this error while compiling a c++ program in sublime-text 3.

How to resolve this error?

Comment: What version of mingw is that?

Comment: I doubt this is Sublime related per se; have you tried running that command manually from inside of a command prompt to see if the error happens there at all?

Answer (score 6):

In my case, this problem is due to `#include<bits/stdc++.h>`. Comment this line and get `#include <iostream>` to solve the problem.

If you have precompiled `<stdc++.h>` then you have stdc++.h.gch file in this path (path could be different on basis of where you installed MinGW and version) :

> C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits

So to solve this problem **delete** stdc++.h.gch file and paste these two commands in your terminal :

1. Go to the path having your precompiled header in command line

> cd C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\9.2.0\include\c++\mingw32\bits

2. Precompile header (mine version is c++17)

> g++ -std=c++17 stdc++.h

I have found this solution on a codechef discussion and it works for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

I got this problem after installing CodeBlocks, maybe it is because of codeblocks `MINGW` settings. My initial `MinGW` is from DEV-C++.

So what I did is this.

1.Delete `"C:\...\GnuWin"` from `PATH`.

2.Ensure that you have your old path to your compiler. In my case it was `"C:\...\DevCPP\Mingw\bin"`

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error popped up right after I updated my SublimeText application to the latest version, so just restarting the system worked for me!

Answer (score 1):

One way this issue can come up is if you're using the gcc-9.2.0-1 MinGW package. Quoting [bustercopley](https://github.com/bustercopley) from [ASLR is now enabled for GCC binaries and it breaks PCH #5719](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5719):

> The binaries in the new gcc-9.2.0-1 packages have ASLR enabled in their PE headers. This breaks using precompiled headers, as they can no longer be mapped at a predictable address. The previous package had 'good' binaries, with ASLR disabled. (This isn't a change in the package itself. I rebuilt the 9.1.0-3 package, and the resulting binaries were 'bad'.)
> [I raised this on the GCC bug tracker](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91440).
>
> [...]
>
> Until a new release of the gcc package comes out, workarounds are to remove the ASLR flag from cc1.exe and cc1plus.exe (e.g., using [setdllcharacteristics](https://blog.didierstevens.com/2010/10/17/setdllcharacteristics/), which you might prefer to compile for yourself) or rebuild gcc from the existing PKGBUILD script (having updated your binutils).

A fix was made for the issue in [`2602139`](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/commit/2602139640f15fb6c58c11c83903f2f3f48b7f13), and another user reported that the issue was fixed after upgrading to gcc-9.2.0-2.

For your reference / learning purposes, I found this by googling "`"internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c" "MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address."`", which led me to https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=101183, which pointed to https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/5719.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what caused this problem today, but I have seen it a few times before.

For me, a full clean and recompile solves it.

Answer (score 0):

I got this same problem after pre-compiling the `stdc++.h` file, to get rid of this error, I removed the compiled version of this header that is `stdc++.gch`.

---

File path of stdc++.h and stdc++.gch is

---

```
C:\Users\UserName\Downloads\MinGW\include\c++\9.2.0\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bits
```

Answer (score 0):

I got this error after updating the sublime text. This error is related to the precompilation of bits/stdc++.h, when we restart the system then it will work.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34830188)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error when compiling some Arduino code, in the Arduino IDE. It occurred just after I updated my graphics driver, too, which might be just a coincidence.

To solve the problem I copied the source file text into a new Arduino project document, and recompiled it. No more error!

It's a very unusual error since there are no actual errors in the code. The Arduino code I was compiling was very simple.