# MinGW windows attempt to access invalid address

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, wxwidgets

I am attempting to create a wxWidgets application using CMAKE and CLion.

I downloaded the source for wxWidgets and placed the source folder in "external," then set up my CMAKE file as follows:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(wxTestProject)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(wxBUILD_SHARED OFF)
add_subdirectory(external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
        wx::net
        wx::core
        wx::base
        )
```

When I try to reload the CMAKE project, I get the following output (which shows success):

```
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\CLion 2023.1.1\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe" -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug "-DCMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM=C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.1.1/bin/ninja/win/x64/ninja.exe" -G Ninja -S F:\Projects\wxTestProject -B F:\Projects\wxTestProject\cmake-build-debug
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.1.1/bin/mingw/bin/gcc.exe - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: C:/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2023.1.1/bin/mingw/bin/g++.exe - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of wchar_t
-- Check size of wchar_t - done
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD
-- Performing Test CMAKE_HAVE_LIBC_PTHREAD - Success
-- Found Threads: TRUE  
-- Performing Test HAVE_WINHTTP_H
-- Performing Test HAVE_WINHTTP_H - Success
-- Looking for d2d1.h
-- Looking for d2d1.h - found
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32   
-- Looking for 4 include files stdlib.h, ..., float.h
-- Looking for 4 include files stdlib.h, ..., float.h - found
-- Looking for va_copy
-- Looking for va_copy - found
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_STRING_COMPARE
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_STRING_COMPARE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_WSTRING
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_WSTRING - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_HASH_MAP
-- Performing Test HAVE_HASH_MAP - Failed
-- Performing Test HAVE_EXT_HASH_MAP
-- Performing Test HAVE_EXT_HASH_MAP - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_UNORDERED_MAP
-- Performing Test HAVE_STD_UNORDERED_MAP - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_TR1_UNORDERED_MAP
-- Performing Test HAVE_TR1_UNORDERED_MAP - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS
-- Performing Test HAVE_GCC_ATOMIC_BUILTINS - Success
-- Performing Test wxHAVE_PTHREAD_CLEANUP
-- Performing Test wxHAVE_PTHREAD_CLEANUP - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_T
-- Performing Test HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_T - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_SETTYPE_DECL
-- Performing Test HAVE_PTHREAD_MUTEXATTR_SETTYPE_DECL - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE___THREAD_KEYWORD
-- Performing Test HAVE___THREAD_KEYWORD - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_ABI_FORCEDUNWIND
-- Performing Test HAVE_ABI_FORCEDUNWIND - Success
-- Looking for localtime_r
-- Looking for localtime_r - not found
-- Looking for gmtime_r
-- Looking for gmtime_r - not found
-- Performing Test wxSIZE_T_IS_NOT_UINT
-- Performing Test wxSIZE_T_IS_NOT_UINT - Success
-- Performing Test wxSIZE_T_IS_NOT_ULONG
-- Performing Test wxSIZE_T_IS_NOT_ULONG - Success
-- Performing Test wxWCHAR_T_IS_REAL_TYPE
-- Performing Test wxWCHAR_T_IS_REAL_TYPE - Success
-- Performing Test HAVE_PW_GECOS
-- Performing Test HAVE_PW_GECOS - Failed
-- Looking for ftime
-- Looking for ftime - not found
-- Looking for wcsftime
-- Looking for wcsftime - found
-- Looking for wprintf
-- Looking for wprintf - found
-- Looking for putws
-- Looking for putws - not found
-- Looking for fputws
-- Looking for fputws - found
-- Looking for vswprintf
-- Looking for vswprintf - found
-- Looking for vswscanf
-- Looking for vswscanf - found
-- Looking for wcsdup
-- Looking for wcsdup - found
-- Looking for wcsnlen
-- Looking for wcsnlen - found
-- Looking for wcscasecmp
-- Looking for wcscasecmp - not found
-- Looking for wcsncasecmp
-- Looking for wcsncasecmp - not found
-- Looking for wcsrctombs
-- Looking for wcsrctombs - not found
-- Looking for wcstoull
-- Looking for wcstoull - found
-- Looking for wcslen
-- Looking for wcslen - found
-- Looking for fsync
-- Looking for fsync - not found
-- Looking for snprintf
-- Looking for snprintf - found
-- Looking for vsnprintf
-- Looking for vsnprintf - found
-- Looking for strnlen
-- Looking for strnlen - found
-- Looking for strtoull
-- Looking for strtoull - found
-- Looking for setpriority
-- Looking for setpriority - not found
-- Looking for gettimeofday
-- Looking for gettimeofday - found
-- Looking for round
-- Looking for round - not found
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/type_traits
-- Looking for C++ include tr1/type_traits - found
-- Looking for C++ include type_traits
-- Looking for C++ include type_traits - found
-- Looking for fcntl.h
-- Looking for fcntl.h - found
-- Looking for langinfo.h
-- Looking for langinfo.h - not found
-- Looking for sched.h
-- Looking for sched.h - found
-- Looking for unistd.h
-- Looking for unistd.h - found
-- Looking for wchar.h
-- Looking for wchar.h - found
-- Looking for wcstr.h
-- Looking for wcstr.h - not found
-- Performing Test wxTEST_TZ_timezone
-- Performing Test wxTEST_TZ_timezone - Success
-- Performing Test WX_GMTOFF_IN_TM
-- Performing Test WX_GMTOFF_IN_TM - Failed
-- Looking for dlopen
-- Looking for dlopen - not found
-- Looking for sys/epoll.h
-- Looking for sys/epoll.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/select.h
-- Looking for sys/select.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/inotify.h
-- Looking for sys/inotify.h - not found
-- Looking for sys/event.h
-- Looking for sys/event.h - not found
-- Looking for xlocale.h
-- Looking for xlocale.h - not found
-- Check size of locale_t
-- Check size of locale_t - failed
-- Check size of size_t
-- Check size of size_t - done
-- Check size of int
-- Check size of int - done
-- Check size of long
-- Check size of long - done
-- Check size of short
-- Check size of short - done
-- Check size of long long
-- Check size of long long - done
-- Check size of ssize_t
-- Check size of ssize_t - done
-- Which libraries should wxWidgets use?
    wxUSE_STL:      OFF      (use C++ STL classes)
    wxUSE_REGEX:    builtin  (enable support for wxRegEx class)
    wxUSE_ZLIB:     builtin  (use zlib for LZW compression)
    wxUSE_EXPAT:    builtin  (use expat for XML parsing)
    wxUSE_LIBJPEG:  builtin  (use libjpeg (JPEG file format))
    wxUSE_LIBPNG:   builtin  (use libpng (PNG image format))
    wxUSE_LIBTIFF:  builtin  (use libtiff (TIFF file format))
    wxUSE_NANOSVG:  builtin  (use NanoSVG for rasterizing SVG)
    wxUSE_LIBLZMA:  OFF      (use liblzma for LZMA compression)

-- Configured wxWidgets 3.2.2 for Windows-10.0.22621
    Min OS Version required at runtime:                Windows XP / Windows Server 2003 (x64 Edition)
    Which GUI toolkit should wxWidgets use?            msw  
    Should wxWidgets be compiled into single library?  OFF
    Should wxWidgets be linked as a shared library?    OFF
    Should wxWidgets support Unicode?                  ON
    What wxWidgets compatibility level should be used? 3.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug

[Finished]
```

However, when attempting to build/run the program, I get the following errors:

```
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/http.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/http.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\net\CMakeFiles\wxnet.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\http.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/http.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/http.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[178/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/protocol.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/protocol.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/protocol.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\net\CMakeFiles\wxnet.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\protocol.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/protocol.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/protocol.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[179/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/socket.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/socket.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/socket.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\net\CMakeFiles\wxnet.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\socket.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/socket.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/socket.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[180/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/sckstrm.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/sckstrm.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/sckstrm.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\net\CMakeFiles\wxnet.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\sckstrm.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/sckstrm.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/sckstrm.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[181/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/webrequest_curl.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/webrequest_curl.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/webrequest_curl.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\net\CMakeFiles\wxnet.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\webrequest_curl.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/webrequest_curl.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/webrequest_curl.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[182/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/webrequest.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/webrequest.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/webrequest.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\net\CMakeFiles\wxnet.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\webrequest.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/net/CMakeFiles/wxnet.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/webrequest.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/webrequest.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[183/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/datstrm.cpp.obj
[184/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/datetime.cpp.obj
[185/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/datetimefmt.cpp.obj
[186/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/arcall.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/arcall.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/3rdparty/pcre/src/wx -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/zlib -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/arcall.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\base\CMakeFiles\wxbase.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\arcall.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/arcall.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/arcall.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[187/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/core/CMakeFiles/wxcore.dir/cmake_pch.hxx.gch
[188/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/cmdline.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/cmdline.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/3rdparty/pcre/src/wx -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/zlib -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/cmdline.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\base\CMakeFiles\wxbase.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\cmdline.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/cmdline.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/cmdline.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[189/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/config.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/config.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/3rdparty/pcre/src/wx -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/zlib -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/config.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\base\CMakeFiles\wxbase.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\config.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/config.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/config.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
[190/646] Building CXX object external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/dircmn.cpp.obj
FAILED: external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/dircmn.cpp.obj 
C:\PROGRA~1\JETBRA~1\CLION2~1.1\bin\mingw\bin\G__~1.EXE -DUNICODE -DWXBUILDING -DWX_PRECOMP -D_UNICODE -D__WXMSW__ -DwxUSE_BASE=1 -DwxUSE_GUI=0 -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/3rdparty/pcre/src/wx -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/zlib -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/lib/gcc_x64_lib/mswud -IF:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/include -g -fdiagnostics-color=always -Wall -Wundef -Wunused-parameter -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -Woverloaded-virtual -pthread -std=gnu++17 -Winvalid-pch -include F:/Projects/wxTestProject/cmake-build-debug/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/cmake_pch.hxx -MD -MT external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/dircmn.cpp.obj -MF external\wxWidgets-3.2.2.1\libs\base\CMakeFiles\wxbase.dir\__\__\__\__\src\common\dircmn.cpp.obj.d -o external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/libs/base/CMakeFiles/wxbase.dir/__/__/__/__/src/common/dircmn.cpp.obj -c F:/Projects/wxTestProject/external/wxWidgets-3.2.2.1/src/common/dircmn.cpp
internal error in mingw32_gt_pch_use_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:186: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address. 
<command-line>: fatal error: had to relocate PCH
compilation terminated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I haven't wrote any code using wxWidgets yet. I'm just trying to get the dependencies to build / link. This is all my CPP has:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I have tried so far:

- A fresh install of CLion
- Downloading the latest version of MinGW and using it instead of the bundled CLion version
- Changing the "wxBUILD_SHARED" flag ON and OFF to see if it made a difference
- Looked for similar error messages on Stack Overflow / Google

I'm really stuck here. I am a rather new C++ developer and I'm not sure where to start.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Edit:

I was able to get it to build and run by setting `wxBUILD_PRECOMP` to `OFF` but I'm still not understanding why that is necessary. Is it an issue with my compiler?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [internal error in mingw32\_gt\_pch\_use\_address, at config/i386/host-mingw32.c:190: MapViewOfFileEx: Attempt to access invalid address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61916030/internal-error-in-mingw32-gt-pch-use-address-at-config-i386-host-mingw32-c190)